# unable to understand Output of the following simple program

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

```
/* A Java program to illustrate working of StringTokenizer
class:*/
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        System.out.println("Using Constructor 3 - ");
        StringTokenizer st3 = 
            new StringTokenizer("JAVA : Code : String", " :", true);
        while (st3.hasMoreTokens())
            System.out.println(st3.nextToken());
    }
}
```

Why is the output of the above program is as follows:

> ```
> Using Constructor 3 - 
> JAVA
>
> :
>
> Code
>
> :
>
> String
> ```

My question is why it has extra newline characters(i.e. it has blank lines after "Java", ":", "Code" etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will become a bit clearer if we make the printing a bit more verbose:

```
while (st3.hasMoreTokens())
  System.out.printf("token: '%s'\n", st3.nextToken());
```

The output will be:

> ```
> token: 'JAVA'
> token: ' '
> token: ':'
> token: ' '
> token: 'Code'
> token: ' '
> token: ':'
> token: ' '
> token: 'String'
> ```

As you see,  and `:` are tokens.
It's because every character in the specified delimiter string `:` are used as delimiters.
And you passed `true` as the 3rd parameter to the constructor of `StringTokenizer`,
and that makes it return the delimiters as tokens.

This is explained in the JavaDoc of [StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)).

Comment: Okay...got it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Because the `true` argument in your constructor means *return delimiters* as separate tokens. So, in addition to the words, you get one token for each space (which appears as a blank line), as well as the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining - [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) . It will split your input by colons and spaces due to " :"; you have defined two tokens, space and colon. Next you are looping through the tokens and doing **println** i.e. printing a new line per token.